# ASP.NET menu control not generate submenus sometimes

Tags: asp.net

I am using ASP.NET Menu control in my Web Application, which generates Menus dynamically from SQL Server database table data. When I run my Web Application, It sometimes doesn't generate sub menus. When I refresh form then It generates sub menus.
I have checked HTML generated for it in which sub menus list not generated so it is not displayed.
What should be the proper solution for this.